# Layered Navigation issue on catalog search result page in magento 2.4.5

Tags: layered-navigation, magento2.4.5

can anyone please tell me why am I not getting layered navigation in search result page in magento2.4.5?

I tried various modules.
currently I don't have any module of Layered Navigation using magento2.4.5 default only.

Comment: are you using sample data or your own products?

Comment: i am using my own products!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the product attributes are filterable. Log into the admin and go to **Store > Products** (under Attributes), now click on one of your attributes you want to be shown in Layered navigation.

Go to "**Storefront Properties**" and set "**Use in Layered Navigation**" to either "Filterable (with results)" or "Filterable (no results)".

**EDIT**

There was an issue on Magento 2.4.5 which layered navigation was not working, it was fixed in this commit  - https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/a9170022cce29993e586ffaa6f4c1cc357ee3b11#diff-1bda4b8d76362780cc546ecd1550493ce8030bea00298543a08831b61022a32d

Please extend the core files and add this change to your code base or apply this change to your core files via a patch.

Comment: it is already "Filterable (with results)" and also "Use in Search Results Layered Navigation" is set to "Yes" but still not visible.
i am not using any third party extension using magento default layered navigation only as i already mentioned above.

Comment: Please try running following commands - php bin/magento in:reset and php bin/magento in:reindex

Comment: Also, it may be some errors due to which it may be not rendering. Please check var/log/system.log and var/log/exception.log and post if you find something that feels connected to the error.

Comment: i tried running both the commands and checked log file but nothing their in it.
i think this is magento2.4.5 bug!

Comment: Did you recently upgrade to 2.4.5?

Comment: yes i recently upgrade to 2.4.5.